# Adding animation to an element with an active state

Tags: html, css, css-animations

For my web assignment I have been given the following instructions for a particular portion of the web page:

> There are five dice in play. When the webpage is loaded, a
>   three-dimensional image must be displayed for each dice.
>   When the dice is clicked, it should display a rolling animation and
>   then it shows a particular dice face (the results of the roll). This
>   value must only be visible when the dice is clicked (active). As an
>   example if you clicked on the dice you might see a dice face showing 5
>   pips demonstrating that you “rolled” a 5.

I am unsure as to how to include the animation as part of the image when it is in  an active state. here is a photo of my page thus far. the dice must display the animation.

[dice game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4y7P.png)

Comment: yes, this an assignment from my intro WEB class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also set a GIF-image as a background image to add an animation.
But here's a working CSS-animation example:

```css
.dices {
  width: 204px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

.dice {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: black;
  margin: 20px 10px;
  transition: background 1s;
  transition: transform 2s;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s;
}

.dice:active {
  background: yellow;
  transform: rotate(720deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(720deg);
}
```

```html
<ul class="dices">
  <li class="dice"></li>
  <li class="dice"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Great solution! One last question. How would I get it to display another image upon completing its 720 degree rotation?